# Multiple If and Then Statements

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Here is a the VBA code that I have, and the only thing that works is the first and last `if` and `then` statements. But the two on the middle don't. What I want to happen is if a Username opens the workbook, excel will only show the worksheet that is intended for that person. That workbook will basically have different worksheet for different people and it will be shared. Does anyone have an idea how to fix the code?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
On Error Resume Next

If VBA.Environ("username") = "Joseph" Then
         Worksheets("Joseph").Visible = xlSheetVisible ' First sheet to be made visible
         Worksheets("Mark").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
         Worksheets("Joel").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
         Worksheets("Ed").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

Else

  If VBA.Environ("username") = "Mark" Then
         Worksheets("Mark").Visible = xlSheetVisible ' First sheet to be made visible
         Worksheets("Joseph").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
         Worksheets("Joel").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
         Worksheets("Ed").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

  Else

    If VBA.Environ("username") = "Joel" Then
         Worksheets("Joel").Visible = xlSheetVisible ' First sheet to be made visible
         Worksheets("Ed").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
         Worksheets("Joseph").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
         Worksheets("Mark").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    Else

      If VBA.Environ("username") = "Ed" Then
         Worksheets("Ed").Visible = xlSheetVisible ' First sheet to be made visible
         Worksheets("Joseph").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
         Worksheets("Mark").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
         Worksheets("Joel").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

      End If

    End If

  End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried a [CASE](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php) statement?

Comment: Hi Michel, Im actually kinda new to VBA. can you help me with the code?

Comment: Just check out the syntax in the link on my comment, it'll show you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

m

Give this code and try and let me know. You do not have to code all the cases because what happens if you add a new user to the company. Look at a better way to do where you will only have to update and array if anything

```
   Option Explicit

' Module Variable to hold the users.
Dim arrUsers As Variant


Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim strUserName As String

    ' Load the arrau of users and the username
    arrUsers = Array("Joseph", "Mark", "Joel", "Ed")
    strUserName = Environ$("username")

    ' Unhide the correct sheet.
    Call MakeVisbleForUser(strUserName)

    On Error Resume Next

End Sub

' Hide all the sheets and show only the one for an user.
Sub MakeVisbleForUser(ByVal strUser As String)

    Dim lCountVisible As Long
    Dim i As Long

    lCountVisible = GetCountVisibleSheets

    ' Hide all the sheets
    For i = LBound(arrUsers) To UBound(arrUsers)
        ' Make sure that the sheet for the user is not hidden
        If Not arrUsers(i) = strUser Then
            ' Make sure that there is at least one sheet visible
            If Not lCountVisible = 1 Then
                Worksheets(arrUsers(i)).Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
                lCountVisible = lCountVisible - 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    ' Show only the one for the user
    Worksheets(strUser).Visible = xlSheetVisible

End Sub

Function GetCountVisibleSheets() As Long

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ret As Long

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            ret = ret + 1
        End If
    Next sh

    ' Return the value
    GetCountVisibleSheets = ret
End Function
```

Thanks I hope it helps :)

Comment: Let me give it a try. Thanks  Alfredo

Comment: Hi, i want to ask what do i need to change in this code? I changed the array because the names i listed are actually just name but in reality the usernames are IDs. like ABC123

Comment: Yes all you have to change is the array :)

Comment: Yeah that's what i did, but whenever I change the array a Run-Time error '9' pops up saying "Subscript out of range".

arrUsers = Array("ABC123", "EFG456", "IJK789")

Comment: I made a small change to the code because we need always at least one sheet visible. Also I would recommend to have some kind of loading sheet like a "Welcome Sheet" so that one is always visible is some that's not in the array tries to open the workbook.

Comment: By the way, can I ask. What if i have a data sheet where in Col A is the date, then Col B are names, and Col C are case numbers. What i want to do is to be able to count how many instance does a name appear in the whole col B but it will consider the date. For example it will only show me the number of instance this persons name appeared today's date. Is that possible? It doesn't have to be a VBA code, it can be just a simple excel formula.

Comment: That new, different question should go on a new, different post.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php) is a good starting point to learn about the `Select Case`.

Outside of that the elseif should be one line

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()


If VBA.Environ("username") = "Joseph" Then
     Worksheets("Joseph").Visible = xlSheetVisible ' First sheet to be made visible
     Worksheets("Mark").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
     Worksheets("Joel").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
     Worksheets("Ed").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

ElseIf VBA.Environ("username") = "Mark" Then
     Worksheets("Mark").Visible = xlSheetVisible ' First sheet to be made visible
     Worksheets("Joseph").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
     Worksheets("Joel").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
     Worksheets("Ed").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

ElseIf VBA.Environ("username") = "Joel" Then
     Worksheets("Joel").Visible = xlSheetVisible ' First sheet to be made visible
     Worksheets("Ed").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
     Worksheets("Joseph").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
     Worksheets("Mark").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

ElseIf VBA.Environ("username") = "Ed" Then
     Worksheets("Ed").Visible = xlSheetVisible ' First sheet to be made visible
     Worksheets("Joseph").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
     Worksheets("Mark").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
     Worksheets("Joel").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

End If


End Sub
```

This then goes in order till it finds one that is true and does that then skips all the rest.  The logic is a little different that the `If` function in excel.  You can have multiple elseifs on one statement.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work. actually already tried ElseIf.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler way:

```
         Worksheets("Joseph").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
         Worksheets("Mark").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
         Worksheets("Joel").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
         Worksheets("Ed").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

         Worksheets(VBA.Environ("username")).Visible = xlSheetVisible
```